# Accounting for spatial autocorrelation in neural network analysis in R

Tags: r, neural-networks, spatial

I have been exploring the use of neural networks to identify relationships between large numbers of differing species and the presence of a specific bacteria in the environment. Previously I had been using mixed effects models, as I could account for spatial autocorrelation in my data.

I was wondering however if anybody knew whether it was possible to incorporate location data to account for spatial autocorrelation in neural network analysis?